# Can you identify these military tunes (17th-century)?

Tags: british-empire, britain, 17th-century, music, great-britain

Would anyone happen to know the names of two historic tunes (fifth and drum) in the Revolutionary War? I linked the descriptions below:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vPbn_uipW10&loop=0&start=01:22&end=01:29

https://youtu.be/UoVCFt0HN9w?t=3431

Many thanks.

Comment: First one is "*Yankee Doodle Dandy*" - rather too basic for this site.

Comment: Second one might be ["*Over there! Over ther!*"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TecxeSmm52o) though thee varying arrangement leaves me unsure.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens No, the first one is not "Yankee Doodle" but seems like [Old 1812](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Lwv79oc6p7Q&feature=youtu.be&t=18).

Comment: @PieterGeerkens No, "Over there, over ther" does not sound like the second one at all. Also, the tune seems to be pre-1800s. So, 1917 seems a hundred years too late. As for its true identity, I just did a search for it, and sadly it looks like it's hard to find. But keep looking!

Comment: Asking the content creator on youtube had no results?

Comment: There is a short flute riff of YDD starting at about 1:06, but I don't think the rest of it is that at all.

Comment: @TomSol The second one, which is harder to identify, is in a miniseries. So, the youtube creator would not know about the specific music.

Comment: @PieterGeerkens, the first one might be a relative of "Yankee Doodle" -- the tune is far older than the modern lyrics, dating back possibly as far as medieval times.

Comment: @Mark Do you have a source that it dates to medieval times?